# Strange series downvoting

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, recent-activity

Two hours ago, several of my answers and questions were downvoted:

[image]

So my question is:

- was there some kind of reputation recalculation?
- does someone really not like my answering/asking style?
- is this a coincidence (although it barely appeared in a year, the chances are certainly non-zero and finite)?

---

**Update:** So "`Serial downvoting reversed`". Hmm, "nice" certainly, but I'd still like to know what was going on?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Voting is intended to be anonymous, and so there is a limited amount that we can say about specific votes. That said, there is some information we can pick up about patterns.

The automated script which reverses 'serial' votes *does* know who votes for who. So the fact that it's acted here suggests that there was some pattern here. There is also a certain amount of voting pattern information available to moderators, and there is something there which suggests a pattern rather than a random event. As it's been handled by the script, I don't think there is anything to actually do here at the moment.

Comment: I totally get this, of cause voting must be anonymous. My problem probably is that I don't get the concept of trolling, or, for the other case, like to confront people directly if I have a problem with them. Either way, nice to know that the automated scripts work that well, and thanks for your answer.

Comment: @TomBombadil It doesn't work that well actually. It ripped egreg's 4k points (WTF?) it didn't even scratch him anyway but still sometimes it gives false positives http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/serial-upvoting-reversed

Comment: @percusse That was to do with upvoting, where I think it's harder to get things 'right'. Multiple downvotes are probably easy to handle (it's just a question of a numerical threshold for 24 h).

Comment: After seeing how egreg's case is handled, I doubt any algorithm :)

Comment: -4K points? Wow, that would be like halving my score X-P

Comment: @TomBombadil Actually I lost only less than 200, in that occasion, because I had plenty of upvotes over the cap in the days where the votes were reversed. I still think that the algorithm is flawed and have received no answer better than "thus it is, period".